# Problems with (PreparedStatement prest) in retrieving data from the database

Tags: java, mysql

```
        query="select friend_uname from myfriends";//SELECT ALL THE FRIENDS OF THE USER
        System.out.println(query);
        rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);     

        query="select * from service_provider where source=\""+source+"\" and dest=\""+dest+"\"    and resources>0 and provider_name IN(?);";
        System.out.println(query);
        prest=conn.prepareStatement(query);

        while(rs.next())
        {
        x=rs.getString("friend_uname");//SELECT THE FRIEND NAMES OF THE USER ONE BY ONE...
        System.out.println("THE friend_uname IS"+ x);
        prest.setString(1,x);//SET THE iTH POSITION OF THE STRING AS THE FRIEND NAME
        }
```

Comment: I have 2 tables 'myfriends' and 'people' in MYSQL database.
      I want to select all those service_providers who are in 'myfriends' table.
      Since I first need to find out who my friends are and then use it to extract      from the 'service_provider' table I used the following.Is it correct?

Comment: Please help friends.I have used it the data retrieved in a jTable and sometimes the list of people are shown in the table and sometimes they are not!Can there be any other possible reason!!!

Comment: In the above,i had initialsed as:PreparedStatement prest;Connection conn=null; ResultSet rs=null; and so on..

Comment: Why are you adding more information in *comments* rather than by editing your *question*? You should also look at reformatting the code in the question to make it more readable.

Comment: Sorry Jon,I really donot know where to post the question..I just saw a space to insert the code.When I inserted the question too,it showed indentation errors.So I posted it in the comments!:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this query

```
query="select * from service_provider where source=\""+source+"\" and dest=\""+dest+"\"  and resources>0 and provider_name IN(select friend_uname from myfriends)";
```

or try with the join query

```
query="select sp.* from service_provider sp, myfriends myfrnd where sp.source=\""+source+"\" and sp.dest=\""+dest+"\"  and sp.resources>0 and sp.provider_name=myfrnd.friend_uname";
```

Comment: THANX PRATIK...EXACTLY AS I WAS THINKING!!

Comment: BUT FOR THE FIRST QUERY HOW WILL THE 'select friend_uname from myfriends' get executed...I am using it in a Java application!!!----->JDBC to connect with a MYSQL database!

Comment: @kosmicbug as the sub query so first sub query was executed and then it's result pass to the parent query, so it's nested query no need to fire different query, individually and if my answer write u should accept it that how stack overflow work. have a good day